# How to update Angular Material Table dynamically with observable

Tags: angular

I want my Angular Material Table to dynamically update whenever my global array for all the `appUsers: AppUser[]` in my `AppUserService` is updated.

I know that the solution I have right know is working fine if the table is constructed with a `*ngFor`. But it's working a bit differently with Angular Material Table.

Angular Material's [official documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#observable-stream-of-data-arrays) says:

> An alternative approach to providing data to the table is by passing an Observable stream that emits the data array to be rendered each time it is changed. The table will listen to this stream and automatically trigger an update to the rows each time a new data array is emitted.

This is what I think I'm after but I can't find any real examples.

`AdminComponent` holds the data source for my table.

```
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<AppUser>();
  private getAppUsersSubscription: Subscription;

  columnsToDisplay = ['userName', 'lastLogin', 'changePassword', 'deleteCustomer'];

  constructor(
    private appUserService: AppUserService,
    private newCustomerDialog: MatDialog) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAppUsersSubscription = this.appUserService.getAppUsers().subscribe(
      (response: AppUser[]) => {
        this.dataSource.data = response;
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

  newAppUser() {
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;

    this.newCustomerDialog.open(NewAppUserComponent, dialogConfig);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.getAppUsersSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

`admin.component.html` Here's the view.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 new">
            <button class="btn btn-primary new-button" (click)="newAppUser()">New Customer</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 new">
            <button class="btn btn-primary new-button">New Setting</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs [dynamicHeight]="true">
        <mat-tab label="Customers">
            <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
                <ng-container matColumnDef="userName">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Customer </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let appUser"> {{ appUser.userName }} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="lastLogin">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Last Login </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let appUser"> {{ appUser.lastLogin | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm' }} </td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="changePassword">
                    <th class="text-center" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Change Password </th>
                    <td class="clickable" mat-cell *matCellDef="let appUser"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></td>
                </ng-container>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="deleteCustomer">
                    <th class="text-center" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Delete Customer </th>
                    <td class="clickable" mat-cell *matCellDef="let appUser"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></td>
                </ng-container>

                <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
                <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let myRowData; columns: columnsToDisplay"></tr>
            </table>
        </mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Settings">

        </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
</div>
```

`NewAppUserComponent` is a dialog window component where I create a new `AppUser`

```
export class NewAppUserComponent implements OnInit {

  newAppUserForm: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  appUser: AppUser;

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<NewAppUserComponent>,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private appUserService: AppUserService
  ) {
    this.appUser = new AppUser();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.newAppUserForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      userName: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
      confirmPassword: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  get f() {
    return this.newAppUserForm.controls;
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;

    this.appUser.userName = this.f.userName.value;
    this.appUser.password = this.f.password.value;

    this.appUserService.postAppUser(this.appUser)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.dialogRef.close();
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      )
  }

  onCancel() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

`AppUserService` posts the `AppUser` to the API and receives a copy if everything went well. I push the newly created `AppUser` to my global array of `appUsers: AppUser[]`. I want this change to be reflected for my table in `AdminComponent`.

```
export class AppUserService {

  public appUsers: AppUser[];
  private appUsersSubject: BehaviorSubject<AppUser[]>;
  public appUsersObservable: Observable<AppUser[]>;

  constructor(private repository: RepositoryService) {
    this.appUsers = new Array<AppUser>();
    this.appUsersSubject = new BehaviorSubject<AppUser[]>(null);
    this.appUsersObservable = this.appUsersSubject.asObservable();
  }

  getAppUsers(): Observable<AppUser[]> {
    let api: string = "api/appuser";
    return this.repository.get(api).pipe(
      map(response => {
        this.appUsers = Object.assign(this.appUsers, response);
        this.appUsersSubject.next(this.appUsers);
        return this.appUsers;
      })
    );
  }

  postAppUser(appUser: AppUser): Observable<AppUser> {
    let api: string = "api/appuser";
    return this.repository.post(api, appUser).pipe(
      map(response => {
        let appUser = new AppUser();
        appUser = Object.assign(appUser, response);
        // Add new AppUser to AppUsers array
        this.appUsers.push(appUser);
        return appUser;
      })
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code to reset the dataSource.data array to empty array and then append the response array to it to trigger change detection.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.getAppUsersSubscription = this.appUserService.getAppUsers().subscribe(
      (response: AppUser[]) => {
        this.dataSource.data = [];
        this.dataSource.data.push(...response);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, no change.

Comment: Can you add the view code where datasource.data is bound to element?

Comment: Check the updated answer. `this.dataSource.data.push(...response);`

Comment: `this.dataSource.data.push(...response);` with this the table does not show any data

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by adding the following.

`admin.component.html` Here I added a reference to the MatTable called `#appUserTable` and passed that reference to `(click)="newAppUser(appUserTable)`

```
<table mat-table #appUserTable [dataSource]="dataSource">
</table>

...

<button class="btn btn-primary new-button" (click)="newAppUser(appUserTable)">New Customer</button>
```

`admin.component.ts` Here I fetch the reference and pass it to `new-appuser.component.ts`

```
newAppUser(appUserTable: MatTable<AppUser>) {
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.data = { appUserTable }

    this.newCustomerDialog.open(NewAppUserComponent, dialogConfig);
  }
```

`new-appuser.component.ts` Now I have the reference in my dialog. When I receive a successfull response from my API call I run `this.appUserTable.renderRows();`

```
appUserTable: MatTable<AppUser>;

  constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data,
  ) {
    this.appUserTable = data.appUserTable;
  }

...

this.appUserService.postAppUser(this.appUser)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.dialogRef.close();
          this.appUserTable.renderRows();
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      )
```